# Slickgrid onChange not keeping cell CSS styles

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I'm dynamically changing the CSS styles to individual cells depending on a drop down in a certain column of that row.  The cells change color no problem, however when I go to the next row and do the same thing....the row previous reverts back to the original default and loses the css that that was applied

```
    "onCellChange" : function(e, args){
     var fooCells = {}; 

    if(args.cell == this.grid.getColumnIndex("test")){
        if(args.item.test == 0 || args.item.test == 1 ){
            if (!fooCells[args.row]) {
                fooCells[args.row] = {};
            } 
            fooCells[args.row][this.grid.getColumns()[this.grid.getColumnIndex("testNumber1")].id] = "slick-test-grayBoxes";
            fooCells[args.row][this.grid.getColumns()[this.grid.getColumnIndex("testNumber2")].id] = "slick-test-grayBoxes";
            this.grid.setCellCssStyles("grayBoxes", fooCells);



            this.dataview.updateItem(args.item.id, args.item);
            this.grid.invalidate();
        }

        if(args.item.test == 2 || args.item.test == 3 ){
            if (!fooCells[args.row]) {
                fooCells[args.row] = {};
            } 
            fooCells[args.row][this.grid.getColumns()[this.grid.getColumnIndex("testNumber2")].id] = "slick-test-grayBoxes";
            fooCells[args.row][this.grid.getColumns()[this.grid.getColumnIndex("testNumber3")].id] = "slick-test-grayBoxes";
            this.grid.setCellCssStyles("grayBoxes", fooCells);



            this.dataview.updateItem(args.item.id, args.item);
            this.grid.invalidate();
        }

    }
    this.grid.invalidateAllRows();
    this.grid.render();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the function, when you call this.grid.invalidateAllRows(); it's wiping out the css styles you've applied. It looks like you're doing this one row at a time - try grid.invalidateRow(); instead. You may need to do grid.invalidateRow(args.item.ID);

Comment: Ah, sorry what you need to identify the row you are working with is args.item.ID, so this.grid.invalidateRow(args.item.id);

Comment: Hey, question...how should I have it set up...just call `grid.invalidateRow(args.item.ID);` at the end of the function and leave everything else the same?

Comment: Yes. In fact, now that I read through the code line by line, you may not even need that call. Try it once with that line commented out, so that at the end of the function, there is only this.grid.render();.  If that doesn't work, then yes the invalidateRows call should go just before this.grid.render.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48003/discussion-between-larsanders-and-doc-holiday)